# Connection created by CONNECT script command disconnected without connecting - ORACLE

Tags: sql, database, docker, oracle11g, apple-m1

I'm trying to use oracle database in my MAC M1, I configured oracle with docker using oracle xe 11g image, and used Colima,
As the steps here show [link](https://docker%20run%20-d%20-p%201521:1521%20-e%20ORACLE_PASSWORD=psw%20gvenzl/oracle-xe)

I'm using sql developer to execute my commands.

I want to:

- create a new user
- grant him privileges
- connect to that user
- and execute commands ( creating tables ..)

**The issue is that:**

My connect command is not connecting and I'm still having SYS as current user **even though I'm not running line by line my script.**

[as show below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVL2g.png)

Please help me fix this issue, and I'm sorry if I didn't formulate my concern as well as it should.

**EDITED**

If I try to create a proxy user, this is what happens, still not connecting.

[check here please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNqLF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when you connect as user proxy and type `show user` you will be connected as DBAIOT, but you will need to select in Developer both statements and execute them, because you will be automatically logged out to `SYS` user.

```
create user DBAIOT identified by psw;
grant all privileges to DBAIOT;
show user 

create user proxy_user identified by proxy
grant create session to proxy_user; 
alter user DBAIOT grant connect through proxy_user; 

conn proxy_user[DBAIOT]/proxy
show user
```

EDIT 2:

This is how it is intended to work take a look at my screenshot.
[image]

I've selected firstly to login and then to print me the current user and after it executed the statement it connects again to SYS. Now whatever I do next I need to select the connect query and execute everything else e.g. CREATE TABLE.

[image]

As you can see the table is created and we are disconnected and connected to SYS user which I connect at the beginning.

Now we can check with SYS user who is the owner of the table.

[image]

And as we can see the owner is DBAIOT and we can see the Customers table.

Or you can connect again as DBAIOT user and then you will always execute statements as DBAIOT user.

[image]

Comment: I tried that, I know that connect executes what's afterwards and disconnects automatically, since Im used to use it in my old mac, but the problem right now is it's not even writing: connected, it's directly showing the message: Connection created by CONNECT script command disconnected.
thank you for your help

Comment: @Formerz You will need to create proxy user and login via proxy user to the DBAIOT. Check my edited answer.

Comment: @Formerz But that is fine, I understand the question now, you need to select with mouse the connection string and everything you want to execute. Which means everything from `connect DBAIOT/psw;' , with mouse means choose the lines you want to execute and they have to be marked blue, same as when you select files you want to copy. And then everything is going to be executed as DBIOT and after finish you will be disconnected and connected to user before which I guess is SYS.

Comment: Please check my edit as I tried to perform your suggestion, Is it possible that the problem is my oracle version or configuration ?

Comment: Check my edited answer